# Problem with my code to find if a number is divisible by a perfect square

Tags: c

So I built a program to find if a number is divisible by a perfect square (i.e 4, 9, 16, 25...). However,  it seems that my number never gets checked after 4 as it exits the loop after getting checked by 4. But I need it need to be checked for all squares up to that initial number that I input. Here is the for loop that I used:

```
for(i=2; i < x; i++) {
      if ( x%(i*i) == 0) {
          printf("%d is divisible by a perfect square.\n", x);
          break;
      }

      else {
          printf("%d is not divisible by a perfect square.\n", x);
          break;
      }
  }
```

Now how do I make my program check for all the squares?

Comment: This is a perfect case for some [*rubber duck debugging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Explain your code, line by line, to your (possibly imaginary) rubber duck, and see what "it" tells you.

Comment: I'm amazed that it got as far as 4.

Comment: Starting the loop at 2 because the first perfect square number is 4. So since i will be squared it will 2*2 which is 4

Comment: @reyrobs When you want to print the "number is not divisible by a perfect square" message? is it when  the number is not divisible by all the perfect square below the number?

Comment: @kiran Biradar I want the message to print after the number inputted has been checked if it is divisible by all the perfect squares. So let's say I input the number 30: it should check for if 30 is divisible by 4, then by 9, then by 16, then 25. And it's not so it should print ("30 is not divisible by a perfect square. ")

Comment: If the entered number is divisible by at least one perfect square then you want to print ("30 is divisible by a perfect square. ") ?

Comment: @kiranBiradar yes exactly.

Comment: @reyrobs answer from Parth Sarthi Sharma is exactly what you are looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for loop` ends when you hit a `break`. And you always hit a `break`!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int flag = 0;
for(i = 2; i < x; i++){
    if ( x % (i*i) == 0){
        printf("%d is divisible by a perfect square.\n", x);
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }
}
if(flag == 0){
    printf("%d is not divisible by a perfect square.\n", x);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Break will get you out of the last loop, so remove the break statement and then use it:

```
   for(i=2; i < x; i++) {
         if ( x%(i*i) == 0) 
              printf("%d is divisible by a perfect square.\n", x);

          else 
               printf("%d is not divisible by a perfect square.\n", x);

     }
```

Comment: if you don't break break it's going to print after checking for each square.

Comment: @reyorbs please read the question again & expalin the downvoters: "But I need it need to be checked for all squares up to that initial number that I input."

Comment: @kiranBiradar Can you explain your down-vote and comment?

Comment: Yes OP's question is not clear but I'm not able to remove my down vote it is locked.

Answer (score -1):

break will break for loop not if , so you need to use "continue" or don't put any thing

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 25;
    int i = 0;

    for(i=2; i < x; i++) {
          if ( x%(i*i) == 0) {
              printf("%d is divisible by a perfect square. when i =%d\n",x,i) ;
              continue;
          }
      }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah it doesn't work man. I only need one output. With this I'm getting loads of outputs because it prints each time it checks if divisible by a perfect square.

Comment: just remove the "else" block